# Problems getting a json from a site

Tags: java, json, url, request

I'm trying to retrieve the json that lies right here https://challonge.com/api/tournaments/jupiter-JFC14.json?include_matches=1&include_participants=1&api_key=MY-API-KEY

(if you want to see the content generate an api key in the developer settings in the challonge site but it's not really important)

from the browser i have no problems, but when i do it from a java application i get this http://pastebin.com/6gkSaC4r

the code i use is this

```
InputStream input = null;
    OutputStream output = null;
    try {
        URL url =new URL(https://challonge.com/api/tournaments/jupiter-JFC14.json?include_matches=1&include_participants=1&api_key=MY-API-KEY);
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        input = con.getInputStream();
        output = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/giuseppe/Desktop/challonges/output2.json");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        for (int length = 0; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    } finally {
        if (output != null) try { output.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
        if (input != null) try { input.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
    }
```

I'm not experienced in this, so I don't really understand why it happens and i don't know how to proceed in order to correct it. Any help is welcome.

Comment: URL must be in quotation marks. Constructor gets String.

Comment: actually in the real code it's something like this URL jsonpage = new URL(getjson);